# How to add Blogger <data:> tags inside meta tags in HTML

Tags: html, xml, templates, meta-tags, blogger

Well I have a Blogger template tag which looks like this `<data:post.title/>` which serves the post title directly via the server and I wish to include this as the meta description for which I tried it something like this

```
<meta name='description' content='<data:post.title/>' />
```

but this fails because of XML and XHTML platform. I thought of using PHP to render the same but the platform(Blogger Blogspot) doesn't support PHP either and obviously usage of scripts is a big no no considering crawlers won't crawl them. Now I need a solution to add these to the template dynamically using the data tag and also should be crawlable.

Note: Manually adding meta tags for each post is a big no no considering how much lengthier it will get inside the html template besides that it's not productive at all for 1000's of posts besides that everything is there the data tag and all I need is a way to include it inside the meta tag. Many many thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would you want to repeat the post title in the description anyway? Better to have it default to the first few sentences of the post if you can't write the content yourself.

Comment: @jeffkee what about meta keywords? I didn't mention about keywords because I thought if someone answered this then I did apply the same for keywords as well. Actually I wish to include the title in the keywords using the data tag.

Comment: Meta keywords are dead according to Matt Cutts at Google. Waste of time. Focus on <title> and <meta name="description">. That's how I do my SEO. As for your above question regarding how the <data> xml tags work, I unfortunately cannot help you as I only use Wordpress or custom coded websites. :(

Comment: @jeffkee no problem ! I actually found a solution while going through meta archives. :D

Comment: @Geniusknight: Feel free to provide your solution in an answer (and you can mark it as solved if it fixes your problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to convert the code into XHTML, All it needs is a parsing declaration which I found while reading about meta tags in this [article](http://geniushowto.blogspot.com/2014/07/add-meta-keywords-to-each-blog-post-in-blogger.html#method2).

```
<meta name='description' expr:content='data:post.title' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<meta name='description' content='data:post.title' />
```